# why grouping does not group salesPerson and LastName properly?

Tags: c#, linq

hi i have the following code to group `Customers` of the `Advertureworks2008R2LT` by `SalesPerson` and customers' `last name`.

```
var dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

var groupedCust = (from c in dc.Customers
                  group c by new { c.SalesPerson, c.LastName }).Take(10);

foreach (var item in groupedCust)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n***{0}***", item.Key.SalesPerson);
    Console.WriteLine("==========================");

    Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", item.Key.LastName);
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");

    foreach (var item2 in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item2.LastName, item2.FirstName);
    }
}
```

I was using `LINQ2SQL` just for the demo. the problem was it does not group with sales person named `"adventure-works\shu0"` there are occurrences of the `adventure-works\shu0` in between there is sales person called `"adventure-works\linda3"`. But this shouldnt happen because `linda3` must come after all `shu0`. why this happens and how do i fix this?

here is the result of the query execution:

```
***adventure-works\pamela0***
==========================

Gee
-------------------------
Gee, Orlando
Gee, Orlando

***adventure-works\david8***
==========================

Harris
-------------------------
Harris, Keith
Harris, Keith

***adventure-works\jillian0***
==========================

Carreras
-------------------------
Carreras, Donna
Carreras, Donna

***adventure-works\jillian0***
==========================

Gates
-------------------------
Gates, Janet
Gates, Janet

***adventure-works\shu0***
==========================

Harrington
-------------------------
Harrington, Lucy
Harrington, Lucy

***adventure-works\linda3***
==========================

Carroll
-------------------------
Carroll, Rosmarie
Carroll, Rosmarie

***adventure-works\shu0***
==========================

Gash
-------------------------
Gash, Dominic
Gash, Dominic

***adventure-works\josé1***
==========================

Garza
-------------------------
Garza, Kathleen
Garza, Kathleen

***adventure-works\josé1***
==========================

Harding
-------------------------
Harding, Katherine
Harding, Katherine

***adventure-works\garrett1***
==========================

Caprio
-------------------------
Caprio, Johnny
Caprio, Johnny
```

Comment: Your grouping is fine, you just didn't order

Comment: @Rob same error i have uploaded a youtube video https://youtu.be/CtJnf1qkLc8

Comment: Please don't link videos, it's a lot quicker and simpler to write your issue in text. Anyway, can you explain ***why*** `linda3` must come after `shu0`? It's not alphabetical order, so what's your criteria for ordering?

Comment: @Rob all in ascending order ordering properties are SalesPerson and customer last name. there are two shu0 in between those two there is linda3, that was the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that there is a difference between how LINQ to SQL/LINQ to Entities handle grouping when compared to how it is done for LINQ to Objects.

Basically when you use the `groupby` clause (or the `GroupBy` method) in L2S/L2E the ordering is stripped off of the generated SQL.  The result is that the SQL server will return the results in some arbitrary ordering that you have no control over... unless you specify the ordering after the group operation.

```
var groupedCust =
(
    from c in dc.Customers
    group c by new { c.SalesPerson, c.LastName } into grp
    orderby grp.Key.SalesPerson, grp.Key.LastName
    select grp
).Take(10);
```

---

That should produce the output you were after, but there is a caveat when querying groups that way in LINQ to SQL.  When you subsequently enumerate the results LINQ will issue a query for each group with the group key characteristics to get back the records that correspond to the group.  This means multiple round trips to the database instead of just getting a bunch of records to start with.

To get the records you want - and only the records you want - from the database you can join against the group query, fetch the matching records, then regroup them in memory.

Or to put it in code:

```
// when enumerated this will result in one SQL statement
var groupingSource = 
(
    from key in
    (
        from gc in dc.Customers
        group 1 by new { gc.SalesPerson, gc.LastName } into grp
        orderby grp.Key.SalesPerson, grp.Key.LastName
        select grp.Key
    ).Take(10)

    join c in dc.Customers on key equals new { c.SalesPerson, c.LastName }
    select c
);

// get the records and re-group them
var groupedCust = 
    from c in groupingSource.AsEnumerable()
    group c by new { c.SalesPerson, c.LastName } into grp
    orderby grp.Key.SalesPerson, grp.Key.LastName
    select grp;
```

The `AsEnumerable` in there will pull the records from the database into memory and do the rest of the expression as LINQ to Objects... which will give you the results you expect with only a single call to the database instead of 11 separate calls.  When you're pulling a *lot* of groups down from the database it makes a real difference, believe me.

Comment: thats a very comprehensive answer, i wish i could add another vote :) thanks

Comment: I prefer giving more information than less, where it makes sense to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

The output you're getting is perfectly fine for the LINQ/SQL you've given.

But try this to see if you get the results you want:

```
var groupedCust =
(
    from c in dc.Customers
    orderby c.LastName
    orderby c.SalesPerson
    group c by new { c.SalesPerson, c.LastName }
).Take(10);
```

Comment: still produces the same error i have uploaded a youtube video on this https://youtu.be/CtJnf1qkLc8

Comment: @PhillGreggan - Then pull back the records into memory (`.ToArray()`), then sort and finally group.

Comment: @PhillGreggan @Enigmativity Continuing the thread here so it's not spread out. This will still not sort the results, because we're grouping after the order. The `orderby` should come after the grouping.. Ie, `... group c by new { c.SalesPerson, c.LastName }).OrderBy(g => g.Key.LastName).ThenBy(g => g.Key.SalesPerson).Take(10);`